# Mysteriously wrong values of numerical fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoid

I've spent the last 2 days investigating this mind-bending issue:I have an index with custom mappings on which I perform some aggregations. The problem is that in the results of the aggregation on numerical fields,it returns values that do not appear in the database from which the data was imported, even though the number of results is the same.

I found a similar issue [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sum-aggregation-returning-very-small-unrelated-values/26890/4) where the problem was inconsistent mapping of a field across an index, but in my case it is mapped as the same type. The problem happens with the fields: `award.value.amount`, `award.value.x_amountEur`, `tender.value.x_amountEur` as far as I have checked.This is my current mapping as stated by `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/documents/_mappings?pretty&human'`
(the part that contains the target fields):

```json
     {
      "documents" : {
        "mappings" : {
          "document" : {
            "properties" : {
              "additionalIdentifiers" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "award" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "_id" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "$oid" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "contract_number" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "date" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                      "_id" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "$oid" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "x_day" : {
                        "type" : "integer"
                      },
                      "x_month" : {
                        "type" : "integer"
                      },
                      "x_year" : {
                        "type" : "integer"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "description" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "initialValue" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                      "_id" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "$oid" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "amount" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "currency" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "x_vat" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "minValue" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                      "_id" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "$oid" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "amount" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "x_amountEur" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "title" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "value" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                      "_id" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "$oid" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "amount" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "currency" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "x_amountEur" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "x_vat" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "x_vatbool" : {
                        "type" : "boolean"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "x_initialValue" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                      "_id" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "$oid" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "x_amountEur" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "x_vatbool" : {
                        "type" : "boolean"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "awardCriteria" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "contract_number" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "document_id" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "numberOfTenderers" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "procurementMethod" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "procuring_entity" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "_id" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "$oid" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "address" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                      "_id" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "$oid" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "country" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "countryName" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "email" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "locality" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "postalCode" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "streetAddress" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "telephone" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "x_url" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "x_slug" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              },
              "suppliers" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "_id" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "$oid" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "address" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "_id" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "$oid" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "email" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "locality" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "postalCode" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "streetAddress" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "telephone" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "x_url" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "x_slug" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              },
              "tender" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "_id" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "$oid" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "value" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                      "_id" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "$oid" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "amount" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "currency" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "x_amountEur" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "x_vat" : {
                        "type" : "float"
                      },
                      "x_vatbool" : {
                        "type" : "boolean"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```

This is the aggregation I am using in order to get the values of contracts between each pair of supplier - procuring_entity:

```json
    Document.es.search({
      "search_type": "count" ,
      "body":{
    "aggregations": {
        "entities":{
          "nested": {
            "path": "procuring_entity"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "procuring_entity_names": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "procuring_entity.x_slug",
                "size": 0
              },
              "aggs": {
                "suppliers": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "suppliers"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "suppliers_names": {
                      "terms":{
                        "field": "suppliers.x_slug",
                        "size": 0
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "awards": {
                          "nested": {
                            "path": "award.value"
                          },
                          "aggs": {
                            "award_amounts": {
                              "terms":{
                                "field": "award.value.x_amountEur",
                                "size": 0
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }})
```

The result with type `float` is :

```json
    {"entities"=>
     {"doc_count"=>24300,
      "procuring_entity_names"=>
       {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
        "sum_other_doc_count"=>0,
        "buckets"=>
         [{"key"=>"vsia-bernu-kliniska-universitates-slimnica",
           "doc_count"=>1360,
           "suppliers"=>
            {"doc_count"=>1360,
             "suppliers_names"=>
              {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
               "sum_other_doc_count"=>0,
               "buckets"=>
                [{"key"=>"recipe-plus-as",
                  "doc_count"=>388,
                  "awards"=>
                   {"doc_count"=>388,
                    "awards"=>
                     {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
                      "sum_other_doc_count"=>0,
                      "buckets"=>
                       [{"key"=>3679.086669921875, "doc_count"=>373},
                        {"key"=>0.0, "doc_count"=>12},
                        {"key"=>73610.3203125, "doc_count"=>1},
                        {"key"=>244000.0, "doc_count"=>1},
                        {"key"=>342348.9375, "doc_count"=>1}]}}}
```

The problem is that in MongoDB the same query returns 388  documents that all have `award.value.x_amountEur = 3679.08661250056` , as presented by Mongoid query:

```rb
    Document.where(:"procuring_entity.x_slug" => "vsia-bernu-kliniska-universitates-slimnica")
            .keep_if{|doc| doc.suppliers.first.x_slug == "recipe-plus-as"}
            .map{|doc| doc.award.value.x_amountEur}.uniq 
    =>[3679.08661250056]
```

A query directly into MongoDB  returns the same.
I have also tried to map the targeted fields as `double`, which gave the same result and as `long` which returned the following (even more incorrect result):

```json
   {"entities"=> 
     {"doc_count"=>24300, 
      "procuring_entity_names"=> 
       {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, 
        "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, 
        "buckets"=> 
         [{"key"=>"vsia-bernu-kliniska-universitates-slimnica", 
           "doc_count"=>1360, 
           "suppliers"=> 
            {"doc_count"=>1360, 
             "suppliers_names"=> 
              {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, 
               "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, 
               "buckets"=> 
                [{"key"=>"recipe-plus-as", 
                  "doc_count"=>388, 
                  "awards"=> 
                   {"doc_count"=>388, 
                    "awards"=> 
                     {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, 
                      "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, 
                      "buckets"=> 
                       [{"key"=>3679, "doc_count"=>371}, 
                        {"key"=>0, "doc_count"=>12}, 
                        {"key"=>44300, "doc_count"=>1}, 
                        {"key"=>80472, "doc_count"=>1}, 
                        {"key"=>331636, "doc_count"=>1}, 
                        {"key"=>342348, "doc_count"=>1}, 
                        {"key"=>1658805, "doc_count"=>1}]}}}
```

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.0, mongoid 5.0.1 and [mongoid-elasticsearch](https://github.com/rs-pro/mongoid-elasticsearch) for indexing. I can't think of anything else to do so any suggestion is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: First of all, I would search in ES to see if those documents really exist. For example, get the document that has `244000.0` as `award.value.x_amountEur`. Check to see if it actually exists in the index.

Comment: Also, I tried to test your scenario with ES 2.0 and there is something that I'm missing. I cannot make it create buckets for the `award.value.x_amountEur` unless I use a `reverse_nested` aggregation to "get out" from one nested path and into another. So, instead of the `awards` aggregation that you have I'm using the same aggregation but "wrapped" in a `reverse_nested` aggregation: `"aggs":{"getting_back":{"reverse_nested":{},"aggs":{"awards":{"nested":{"path":"award.value"},"aggs":{"award_amounts":{"terms":{"field":"award.value.x_amountEur"}}}}}}}`. And for this one I am seeing something ok.

Comment: I second what @AndreiStefan said, i.e. you're probably missing a `reverse_nested` aggregation in order to "branch out" from one nested path into another.

Comment: @Andrei Stefan, using `reverse_nested` only for the awards aggregation returned all the values 0. However, following @Val's advice and changing all the `nested` aggregations involved into `reverse_nested` ones returned the proper result. Thank you both!

Comment: Interesting. I'm assuming you added `reverse_nested` for `awards` and `suppliers`, right?

Comment: Also, I think it would be good if you posted the comment as an answer because otherwise the bounty cannot be awarded and will go to waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to test your scenario with ES 2.0 and there is something that I'm missing. I cannot make it create buckets for the `award.value.x_amountEur` unless I use a `reverse_nested` aggregation to "get out" from one nested path and into another.

So, instead of the `awards` aggregation that you have I'm using the same aggregation but "wrapped" in a `reverse_nested` aggregation:

```
  "aggs": {
    "getting_back": {
      "reverse_nested": {},
      "aggs": {
        "awards": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "award.value"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "award_amounts": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "award.value.x_amountEur"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And for this one I am seeing something ok.

**Later edit**: following mine and more general @Val's suggestion, the complete solution was to use `reverse_nested` on both `awards` and `suppliers` aggregations.

Comment: Tricky one, though, interesting use case, might come in handy for me as well :-) Well done!